# How can i encode each string?

Tags: c#, .net

In the end of the loop i'm getting a List and inside i see in each index:

������� ������� ����� �����

This is since the text is in Hebrew.
The encoding code is: 65001

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(65001)

public List<string> GetResponsers(string contents)
        {
            List<string> threadList = new List<string>();
            int f = 0;
            int startPos = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                string firstTag = "<FONT CLASS='text16b'>";
                //string firstTag = ";>";
                string lastTag = "&n";
                //string lastTag = ":בתאריך";
                f = contents.IndexOf(firstTag, startPos);
                if (f == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                int g = contents.IndexOf(lastTag, f);
                startPos = g + lastTag.Length;
                string responser = contents.Substring(f + 2, g - f - 2);
                threadList.Add(responser);
            }
            return threadList;
        }
```

How do i apply the encoding for each responser ?

This is the method after i tried to use encoding:

```
public List<string> GetResponsers(string contents)
        {
            List<string> threadList = new List<string>();
            int f = 0;
            int startPos = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                string firstTag = "<FONT CLASS='text16b'>";
                //string firstTag = ";>";
                string lastTag = "&n";
                //string lastTag = ":בתאריך";
                f = contents.IndexOf(firstTag, startPos);
                if (f == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                int g = contents.IndexOf(lastTag, f);
                startPos = g + lastTag.Length;
                string responser = contents.Substring(f + 2, g - f - 2);
                Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding(65001);
                byte[] isoBytes = iso.GetBytes(responser);
                string ff = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
                responser = ff;
                threadList.Add(responser);
            }
            return threadList;
        }
```

But it didn't change anything.

Comment: What do you mean "apply the encoder"?

Comment: The only thing that you do is to encode a string into bytes, and then decoding it back to the same string, so that doesn't change anything. You are trying to use encoding way too late, that has to be used when the `contents` string is created. Once you have decoded the response using the wrong encoding, it can't reliably be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"it didn't change anything" because

```
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding(65001); 
byte[] isoBytes = iso.GetBytes(responser); 
string ff = iso.GetString(isoBytes)
```

does nothing in the end - it is just like "add 10, remove 10" - nothing changes in the end. [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx) and [GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc(v=vs.110).aspx) are inverse functions when used from the same encoding.

---

You should apply encoding-decoding at the point where you get the data for the string(because there is nothing lost or changed due to the incorrect encoding).

---

But if the string has been already decoded with incorrect encoding you could try to rectify the problem using [Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default(v=vs.110).aspx) encoding to get original bytes and use your local encoding to encode the correctly:

```
byte[] originalBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(mangledStr); 
string correctStr = Encoding.GetEncoding(65001).GetString(originalBytes );
```

But it may or may not work if only the part of string is used depending on the original encoding.

---

The best solution is to use in your original web service some encoding that natively supports your local - [Unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx) or [UTF8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8(v=vs.110).aspx). It will save you from any problems with encoding-decoding.

**P.S.**: Also take into account that VS debugger can sometimes have problems with correct representation of strings when encoding differs from system's encoding - Just in case if you check your string in the debugger. The same applies for some controls and applications.